# Laravel populate checkboxes roles field with user roles on ajax edit modal form

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

Hey guys I could use some help from the stakoverflow comunnity on this one, the thing is I have an index view where all of the methods are fired from, create method works fine, update method works fine too, the problem is when the edit form shows up the checkbox that indicates the user's role doesn't show checked, I have to recheck the checkbox for the method update to work, otherwise it won't work, here is my code.

Edit Modal:

```
{{ Form::open(['autocomplete' => 'off', 'id' => 'edit_user_form']) }}
    <div id="edit_user_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Actualizar Usuario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="response"></div>
                    {{ Form::textGroup('name', 'Nombre', ['id' => 'edit_name']) }}
                    {{ Form::emailGroup('email', 'Correo Electrónico', ['id' => 'edit_email']) }}
                    {{ Form::checkboxGroup('roles', 'Roles', $roles, 'display_name', ['id' => 'edit_roles']) }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    {{ Form::submit('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Regresar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Edit Method:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');

        $user = User::with('roles')->find($id);

        return response()->json($user);
    }
```

Edit Button:

```
protected function getEditButtonAttribute()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->hasPermission('update-users')) {
            if ($this->id != 1) {
                return '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-edit" id="' . $this->id . '">Editar Usuario</a></li>';
            }

            return '';
        }

        return '';
    }
```

Edit Route:

```
Route::get('user/{user}', 'Auth\UserController@edit')->name('user.edit');
```

And finally edit script:

```
edit_name = $('#edit_name');

edit_email = $('#edit_email');

edit_roles = $('#edit_roles');

edit_user_modal = $('#edit_user_modal');

$(document).on('click', '.btn-edit', function () {
    id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ url("user") }}" + "/" + id,
        method: 'GET',
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            edit_name.val(data.name);
            edit_email.val(data.email);
            edit_roles.val(data.roles);
            edit_user_modal.modal('show');
        }
    })
});
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like 'role' is not defined on your User model, but as a relationship. If that's the case, your typical form-model binding is probably not working as you would expect. In order to fix this you could try using the "appends" property for your User model and include "role" as an appended property. Then it will load natively. If that does not work, I would suggest that you simply create the form field yourself, rather than relying on the Form facade, as you will have much more control over the input and can easily override the baked-in functionality of Laravel's form helpers.

Comment: I implemented Laratrust package for roles and permissions; user, role and permissions model all have the correct relation.

Comment: I'm not suggesting your relationships are defined improperly, just that they may not be recognized by the form/model binding unless you manually attach them with the $appends array on the User model. Regardless, it is not much extra code to simply define the input yourself, in which case you could completely control the functionality and not rely on the "black box" of the Form facade. That's my recommendation.

Comment: In your User model, try adding this just within the class declaration:

    protected $appends = array('role');

If that doesn't work, try implementing the input manually. I know that it will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate but It doesn't work, what i need is to fetch the id of the user in the index method, any help with that?